# Can I teach the same course I developed at one university at another university as well?

Tags: teaching, university, lecturer, course-design, lecture-notes

University A hired me to teach a course. It paid the costs of preparation (3 months) and financed tranining sessions to enhance my instructing abilities.

University B now asked me to offer the same course there.

Assuming that my contract with University A is mute on this matter, is there anything to consider when one wants to hold the same course at another university? Is it generally allowed (or discredited) to use the very same contents one developed at one university at another one?

Comment: Did university A ask you to sign anything that allocates the copyright of the material to them?

Comment: There cannot be any limitation on teaching. Perhaps audio visual and stuff like that might be proprietary. I suggest putting a tag Country related because this might unfortunately depend on that.

Comment: The contract you signed may include a stipulation that what you produce and deliver to the students is now owned by the university, at least for the universities I have worked at it is the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say it is generally allowed and that exceptions would be rare. But a policy forbidding it would need to be spelled out.

At one level, universities are in competition with others, but this isn't normally at the level of instruction. At a more important level, universities are cooperative and encourage their faculty to also be cooperative.

I've never heard of a university claiming that any given course was unique to it and therefore proprietary. I once taught in a unique program, but that was just because no one else took it up. We certainly didn't claim ownership over it.

Another issue, however, is that universities may frown on faculty teaching at two places simultaneously, no matter the course.